# Email not save in session table [Codeigniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to save user email in session but it does not work.

```
            $data=array(
            'ip_address'   => $ip
            ,'timestamp'    => $now
            ,'data'         => NULL
            ,'browser'      => $agent
            ,'user_info'    => $email
            );
        $this->session->set_userdata('ci_sessions',$data);
```

Here is pic of session table:
[image]

Here is config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';//its your table name name
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: In `$email` is correct data? If You set there any string it's saved in DB?

Comment: Edit your question with your config session info.

Comment: @Mr.ED check config session info

Comment: I thin you should be saving it in array in the data. `'data' => array('email' => $email)` But also you have the comma back to front.

Comment: use like this : $this->session->set_userdata($data);

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma `,` before `ip_address`. if `set_userdata` expects 5 arguments, the first one is empty and `user_info` is the 6th one.